# Implement Oauth 2.0 authentication mechanism using passport

Tags: node.js, oauth, passport.js

I need to implement Oauth 2.0 in my node js app using passport.But Oauth 2.0 documentation in passport does not contain schema definition and user registration and refresh token.Is there any Restful API implementation in node js with passport similar to authentication mechanism in Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For REST API implementation with Node.js and passport.js oAuth 2.0, you can refer to [this](http://aleksandrov.ws/2013/09/12/restful-api-with-nodejs-plus-mongodb/) article. For more information, you can refer to [this StackOverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285642/nodejs-rest-authentication-using-passport-and-oauth2-social-network)

Answer (score 0):

Use passport-oauth2 for this,

**npm install passport-oauth2**

```js
passport.use(new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: 'https://www.example.com/oauth2/authorize',
    tokenURL: 'https://www.example.com/oauth2/token',
    clientID: EXAMPLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: EXAMPLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/example/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    User.findOrCreate({ exampleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

For more details refer [Here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2)